# Reference already-deployed contracts in testing-suite

Tags: testing, brownie

when I run my deploy script in console, *ContractContainer* has the newly deployed contract-address. But when I try to reference that in tests, *ContractContainer* seems to be empty. What would be the correct way to reference these already-deployed contracts in my tests easily?

For example: Truffle has an *DeployedAddresses* contract that is available for import in its Solidity testing suite... So I can reference already-deployed contract(-addresses) like this: `address contractAddress = DeployedAdresses.ContractName()`

For Brownie the somewhat equivalent seems to be the *ContractContainer*, being filled with *ProjectContract* objects (upon deployment). When I run my deploy script in console, the *ContractContainer* is filled and *ProjectContract* available to the console. Yet, when I try to reference this in my tests, it seems to be empty. Am I missing something?

Is there a way to run tests in the console? Maybe that would be part of the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a development chain (those under the `Development` section after running `brownie networks list`), all contracts deployed only live in the instance that the chain is alive, so every time you run a new script, the entire blockchain is scrapped.

You can access deployed contracts on a chain, by referencing their index. Let's say you have a contract named `SimpleStorage`, you could reference the most recently deploy contract with:

```py
simple_storage = SimpleStorage[-1]
```

But again, those contracts will have to have been deployed.